# How can I redirect to another page with screen already at the bottom of the page?

Tags: redirect

I'm using buddypress, I have a link that redirect to /profile/change-avatar/ so what I want is after i arrived at the change avatar page, the screen already at the bottom of the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an anchor with an ID in the new page where you want it to 'arrive'

```
<a id="bottom"></a>
```

And reference in your link with #:

```
profile/change-avatar#bottom
```

Hope that helps!